# Quotient group of the non-zero complex numbers

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers and
let $P$ denote the subgroup of positive (real) numbers. I am trying to find  the quotient
group $\mathbb{C}/P$. Please help.

Comment: Hint: What would a coset of $P$ look like, geometrically?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Every complex number has the form $re^{i\theta}$. You can dispense with that $r$...